# Cache Fails with Multiple Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, caching, onclick

I have a flow where I technically have 2 addresses, but it appears as 3 different pages.

- The first page, eligibility.aspx (which appears as two: Member
  Search, and Member Search Results). The Member Search Results can
  display 0-many results.
- Second page(third in the process) is
  /members/member-detail. This is accessed after clicking an Individual
  member from the Member Search Results screen

**What I want**:

I want users to be able to go from screen 3(member-detail) back to Member Search Results, and even to Member Search. But when they go back to Member Search, I want any information typed in the fields to disappear.

I tried doing this with cache, but then it fails with the following when I go from screen 3 to screen 2:

***Webpage has expired***

---

**Code:** (eligibility/default.aspx.cs):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

.....

Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
            Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

protected void lnkSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ShouldSearch = false;
            litError.Text = "";
            ClearAllSearchInputVars();

            // Member ID
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbSearchMemberID.Text))
                Search_MemberID = tbSearchMemberID.Text;
                tbSearchMemberID.Text = ""; // clear field after clicking search

  protected void ClearAllSearchInputVars()
        {
            Search_MemberID = "";
            Search_MemberFirstName = "";
            Search_MemberLastName = "";
            Search_DateOfBirth = "";
            Search_Gender = "";
        }

protected void LoadMember(string memberID, string memberSequenceID = null)
        //protected void LoadMember(int memberID, string memberSequenceID=null)
        {
            tbSearchMemberID.Text = ""; //may just want to set text to Empty String like this 
            tbDateOfBirth.Text = "";
            tbSearchMemberLastName.Text = "";
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(memberSequenceID))
                Response.Redirect(String.Format("/members/member-detail/{0}", memberID));
            else
                Response.Redirect(String.Format("/members/member-detail/{0}/{1}", memberID, memberSequenceID));            
        }
```

I saw this used in a number of solutions on SO, so it seems like it should be whats needed. Can I not use this cache feature when I have multiple screens on a page?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you aren't using the `OutputCache` directive? https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/308375/how-to-control-page-output-caching-in-asp-net-by-using-visual-c-net

Comment: Thanks. Can this just be placed at the top of the page as such: <%@ OutputCache Duration="60" VaryByParam="*" %>
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="blah.e._default" %>

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Screen 2 to 1 works great, but Screen 3 to 2 still gets the message "Webpage has expired"  (from /members/member-detail/number/number back to /eligibility)